# How to use server-side rendering in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-universal

I have a web app developed with Angular 2 which communicates with Java APIs on the server to fetch data. Everything is working fine except the pages are not indexed by search engine (except Google which supports script generated tags).

I've googled a lot and found that this can be achieved by "server side rendering" and there are libraries available to achieve this but all of these are commercial products that require payment.

I have come across Angular Universal which is not a commercial product, can we use it to solve our issue? If it can then how can we hook it up to our existing app?

Comment: I just found that we can install community version of prerender and proxy webapp to solve this issue, is this correct approach to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use angular2 universal with server side JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699744/can-we-use-angular2-universal-with-server-side-java)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path there are two ways to achieve your objective

- If you are using @angular/cli for developing angular app then you can only follow this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering)
- If you developing with your own webpack.config file then there are lot of options available, best of them is [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) , which is featued in official documentation of angular/universal

While continuing with @angular/cli, there is a little caveat that it doesn't support lazy loading yet but they are working on it and future is bright with @angular/cli. If you want to implement lazy loading now only then i will suggest you go ahead with second option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion, can we use prerender (open source) backed by S3 for storing and serving static pages